# Unable to add product in the Wishlist from the category page but it is working fine for Product display page in magento 2.4.5-p4

Tags: adobe, magento2, categories, catalog

Unable to add product in the Wishlist from the category page but it is working fine for Product display page  in Magento 2.4.5-p4 getting error store_base_url/wishlist/index/add/?product=186&uenc=aHR0cHM6Ly9lc3RvcmVkZXYuYWlydGVjaGludGwuY29tL2F1dG9jbGF2ZS90b29sbWFzdGVyci10b29saW5nLW1hdGVyaWFscy5odG1s&form_key=Vj9SXWtGWeRVKiOj&_=1693975109650  not found (404 error).
Can someone help with this ?
I am attaching the picture of the error from the network
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPqys.png)

I tried to reload the page after adding to Wishlist instead of redirecting it to wishlist page , than it is working for Luma theme but giving the same error for smartwave porto theme. Issue came after updation to Magento 2.4.5-p4 it was working fine for magento 2.4.5-p2